# can big sub woofer be a problem for car cng cylinder

Tags: audio, cng

I have an old toyota corolla e 100 sedan. A CNG cylinder is installed in my car because here it is cheaper than octane. I was thinking about setting up a good audio system in my car, which includes a 12 inch or mayb an 18 inch sub woofer. The cng cylinder is installed in the trunk. If I install a sub then it has to be put in the trunk too. So I was wondering would it be a problem for the cylinder? Like when I use really high volume with high bass bits? Will the sub woofer vibration cause any risk for the cylinder? TIA.

Comment: CNG = Compressed Natural Gas for those that don't follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Fuel needs air to burn/explode/ignite

[This video is ample evidence of that](http://channel.nationalgeographic.com/street-genius/videos/more-gas-more-boom/).

Acoustic vibration will have no impact on a CNG tank whose integrity isn't compromised (i.e. doesn't leak).

Even if the tank leaks gas into its surroundings, there needs to be a spark or naked flame to result in an explosion. Acoustic vibration alone won't be enough to cause ignition.

If there was even a remote possibility of igniting an air-fuel mixture with acoustic vibrations it would have been explored as an alternative to (comparatively complex) spark-ignition systems.

---

That said, there is more than one way a CNG tank can go *bang*. Consider the following:

- electrical hazards from installing the subwoofer (electrical shorts, heating effect of high current)
- mechanical integrity of the tank (leaks, corrosion)
- heat in small enclosures

Comment: That was really helpful. Now I just got one question. I did not get the last line of your answer. By saying "heat in small enclosures" did you mean the sub woofer enclosure? If not then what? You know a speaker can get a little bit heat when it produces a lot of dB. So I was just curious which enclosures did you mean?

Comment: @WahidMasud I meant the space where the tank is installed. If the addition of your system is generating a lot of heat then the enclosure temperature will rise

Comment: the good thing is, standard CNG install can take a lot of hat before problems occur. Those canisters are **robust**